# cannot convert from 'const Eigen::GeneralProduct<Lhs,Rhs,ProductType>' to 'double'

Tags: c++, eigen3

I keep getting this error every time I compute this line

```
double k = b.transpose()*Z.inverse()*b;
```

where `Eigen::MatrixXd Z(3,3), b(3,1);`. I've tried casting but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly formulated question, concise and simple. OP showed the code, mentioned what he tried, and asked for a solution, which complies totally with SO. And if you have less experience with `Eigen` it is not at all obvious why the product between a `1 x N` matrix and an `N x 1` matrix is not a scalar (as you learn in highschool), and the compiler spits out a template-kind of error, which is not super obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is by default an Eigen expression (think of it as a matrix, technically is a template type called `Eigen::GeneralProduct<...>`), so even if the matrix is `1 x 1`, it is not implicitly convertible to `double`. What you have to do is to access its `(0)` element (or `(0,0)`, it makes no difference), see below

```
Eigen::MatrixXd Z(3,3), b(3,1);
double k = (b.transpose()*Z.inverse()*b)(0);
```

PS: As mentioned by @ggael, you should use an `Eigen::VectorXd` as the type of `b`, in which case the result is implicitly convertible to a `double`.

Comment: You can also write this as `double k = (b.transpose()*Z.inverse()*b).value()`, which might be a bit more readable (the `value` member function converts a 1-by-1 matrix to a scalar).

Comment: @vsoftco: your answer is true if and only if the user uses general matrices to store vectors, which is a very bad practice with Eigen. Otherwise, such an inner-product **is implicitly convertible** to `double`.

Comment: @ggael thanks for the comment, are you saying that if `b` was declared as a `VectorXd` then the code would've converted implicitly? Ok, just found out by myself it's true and edited my answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, so make sure that b is declared as a `VectorXd` such that Eigen can know at compile-time that result is a `1x1` matrix and so it can be safely converted to a scalar value. Here is a self-contained example:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
int main() {
  int n = 10;
  VectorXd b(n);
  MatrixXd Z(n,n);
  double k = b.transpose() * Z.inverse() * b;
}
```